# OKHttp3: where to download the okhttp3 source code of version 3.14.x version and build it into jar file?

Tags: okhttp

Does any one know where to download the okhttp3 source code of 3.14.x version and build it into jar file? I used it for linux application (not for android).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to the GitHub site, go to "tags", and look for a 3.14 tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IDEs, it should be downloaded automatically as it's published to maven central.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.9/

As @noah says, you can browse it in github https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/okhttp_3.14.x

You can check this out with

```
$ git clone https://github.com/square/okhttp
$ git checkout okhttp_3.14.x
$ mvn package
```